# Best Practice - Collection.add() and handling boolean return value

Tags: java, netbeans, collections

I did not find anything specific to this question.  I have just started working with NetBeans and it thew a 'warning' about a Manual collection add loop:

```
for(String str : strings){ list.add(str) }
```

Net Beans really wanted me to handle the boolean return value from the collection addition:

```
for(String str : strings){ boolean add = list.add(str) }
```

I have never really considered if not storing/handling the return of a collection.add() method as faulty or negligent.  I've seen it regularly to simply ignore the return value since it may not be valuable.  Is this incorrect?  What are the ramifications of not handling the return boolean value?  Or is this just an IDE thing?

Thanks all.

Comment: Well, either you configured your IDE to warn you about that, or it is the default setting. Either way, if you don't need the returned value, then ignore it. And `List#add` is as far as I know (in my experience) rarely used (however `Set#add` quite a bit more).

Comment: @Tom then how do people put things in lists if they don't use `add`?

Comment: @wvdz I meant the returned value :D. Looks like I had a brainfart, when I wrote the last sentence.

Comment: @Tom Ah okay, makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is not about ignoring the return value of `Collection.add` but instead about manually looping through an array and adding to a collection. NetBeans really does not like manual array copies and prefers you use an API method to do the copying.

In your case that would be `list.addAll( Arrays.asList( strings ) )`.

Comment: I have to wonder though... is that really preferable? Given that Arrays.asList is going to create a `new ArrayList`, and `addAll` will just loop over that arrayList. So it seems like it's better in brevity, about the same in clarity, and worse in performance.

Comment: @Mshnik you would have to bring that up with the NetBean's maintainers on why they chose that to be a warning. On NetBeans the preferred way to copy collections or arrays is to use an API provided method. Which is why OP is getting the warning he is asking about.

Comment: That makes sense.  I suppose I have a better grasp of C++ and using pointers (I know not the same thing here), but seeing warnings like that just puts me into the "your not managing memory allocation correctly" space...

Comment: @Mshnik `Arrays.asList` just creates a wrapper around the array; it doesn't copy all the elements. Calling `addAll` is preferable to looping and adding yourself, as it can preallocate space in the destination.

Answer (score 0):

It is the IDE warning to tell you, that the return value not used. You can close this warning in the setting.

**Note:** If you need to test the item was added or not in some special cases, then you can use this returned `boolean` value, otherwise you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

put @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "null", "unused"}) it's funtion
Eg:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "null", "unused"})
private void myfuntion() {
   ...
   for(String str : strings){ list.add(str); }

}
```